# linux: How to disconnect Remote user access?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, remote-access

I am designing an application to access remote screen using vncviewer through QProcess in Qt.
( I am using vino-server at remote desktop)
After login to the remote screen (in fullscreen mode), i want to disconnect the remote sharing and switch back to local screen.

Is there any Qt way to do it?

How to achieve this through linux command line ??

I am using Linux Os (ubuntu).

any idea / suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to resolve this issue.

Considering that the system is under Remote access. To disconnect it from the remote user, just stop the vnc server  and then restart it when required or using timer, restart it after few seconds. This will disconnect the Remote user from the server.

Using command line, it can be done as follow:

1. To Stop VNC Server
   open a terminal and type this command:

   ```
    $ gconftool-2 -s -t bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled false
   ```
2. To Start VNC Server
   open a terminal and type this command:

   ```
    $ gconftool-2 -s -t bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled true
   ```

It can be more simplified by creating two bash shell scripts:

startvnc.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    # This script starts enables System -&gt; Preferences -&gt; Remote Desktop

    gconftool-2 -s -t bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled true</pre>
```

stopvnc.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    # This script starts enables System -&gt; Preferences -&gt; Remote Desktop

    gconftool-2 -s -t bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled false</pre>
```

After creating those scripts, make them executable with this command:

```
    $ chmod +x startvnc.sh
    $ chmod +x stopvnc.sh
```

If you need, make aliases to them.  Open ~/.bashrc in a text editor, scroll to the bottom, and type in these two lines:

```
    alias startvnc=/path/to/your/startvnc.sh
    alias stopvnc=/path/to/your/stopvnc.sh</pre>
```

Now, when you SSH into your box (or open a command line), you can just type

```
    $ startvnc
```

[ to enable Remote Desktop ], or

```
    $ stopvnc
```

[ to disable Remote Desktop ].

Now, In Qt, using QProcess it can be achieved very easily.